# Private members are not inherited (or overridable) by subclasses in Java?

Tags: java, jvm

Isn't that subclass inherits **everything** from superclass true? But subclass could not access its superclass's private attribute/method, but can access its own. So I wrote a test program. But it seems subclass has not one!

```
class a {
    private void set() {
           System.out.println("a.set()");
    }
}
public class b extends a {
//      private void set() {
//      System.out.pritln("b.set()");
//       }
        void f() {
             set();
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
             b b = new b();
             b.f();
        }
}
```

If I comment out  the set() method in b as the example does, it won't compile.

Any idea? Any explanation from JVM view ?

Comment: They're inherited, but not accessible by default.  If you really want to, there are some tricks you can pull to cause them to become accessible at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `private` methods aren't accessible from a derived class. `protected` and `public` are.

When you declare `set` in your derived class, you gain access to this derived version since it's now part of the class (no longer a `private` base class method).

You'd still get an error if you attempted to call `super.set()`.

Edit: the trick aroth's talking about I assume is reflection. :) Don't.

Comment: +1 for the advice against circumventing access privs via relfection

Comment: Thank you L.G. , I konw that  super.set() is no doubt unaccessible(or inaccessible? Orz...). What I'm confused is: since b has inherited everything from a, b has it's own set(), so it uses set() in f(),which is rational,right? I want to konw what is being done under the hood in JVM...

Answer (score 0):

The question is meaningless. Private is private. Invisible to everything outside the current class. If you want 'protected', use it.

Comment: Private is private...until someone uses reflection to find the `Field` and calls `setAccessible(true)` on it.  The question is whether or not the field is inherited, and it is, regardless of whether or not it's actually visible.

Comment: @aroth Although to be fair, I've only seen that done in some "hacks"; not with design-in-mind :)

Comment: @TylerTreat - only **some** ORM or DI frameworks.  Other frameworks require you to expose the attributes via accessible methods or fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something in between, use the "protected" modifier instead of the "private" modifier; protected essentially means private to everything but subclasses.